# How can I set children inside the list?

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch list of data from one table on that table have parent-child relation from "hierCd" and "parentHierCd". In the first time I am getting all parent list. After that when I am building data, I need to get all children of those parents. That can be multi level deep like I show in expected result.

Table have data like below

```
  **hierCd**         **Name**         **parentHierCd**
   TEA-1               tea1              TEA
   TEA-2               tea2              TEA
   TEA-3               tea3              TEA
   TEAA-1              teaa-1            TEA-1
   TEAA-2              teaa-2            TEA-1
   TEAAA-1             teaaa-1           TEAA-1
   ITC-1               itc-1             ITC
   ITC-2               itc-2             ITC
   ITCA-1              itca-1            ITC-1
   ITCA-2              itca-2            ITC-1
```

I mentioned all code.
Hier is entity file, which is mapped from DB. 
Committee is using for setting data in rest api side.

```
//Committee api model class
public class Committee {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private UUID id = null;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = null;

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code = null;

    @JsonProperty("parentCd")
    private String parentCd = null;

    @JsonProperty("children")
    @Valid
    private List<Committee> children = null;

    with getters and setters
}

//Hier entity model class
public class Hier {
    private String hierCd;
    private String hierTyp;
    private String hierName;
    private String uuid;
    private String parentHierCd;

    with getters and setters

}

//This method is calling for get parent record.
public List<Committee> getCommittees(){

    private List<String> PARENT_CDS = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "TEA", "ITC" });

    List<Committee> committees = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Hier> committeeHierarchies = committeeRepository.findParentHiersByHierCdInOrderByHierNameAsc(PARENT_CDS);

    for(Hier hier:committeeHierarchies)
    {
        committees.add(committeeBuilder(hier));
    }

    return committees;

}

// Building committee with sub committee
private Committee committeeBuilder(Hier hier) {
    Committee committee = new Committee();
    committee.setId(UUID.fromString(hier.getUuid()));
    committee.setCode(hier.getHierCd());
    committee.setName(hier.getHierName());
    committee.setParentCd(hier.getParentHierCd());
    if(hiertype.equals("allCommittee")){
        committee.setChildren(getChildrenByParentCd(hier.getHierCd()));
    }
    return committee;
}

//Return sub committees by parent hier code
public List<Committee> getChildrenByParentCd(String parentCd) {
    List<Committee> committees = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Hier> children = committeeRepository.findChildrenByParentHierCd(parentCd);
    for (Hier hier : children) {
        Committee committee = new Committee();
        committee.setId(UUID.fromString(hier.getUuid()));
        committee.setCode(hier.getHierCd());
        committee.setName(hier.getHierName());
        committee.setParentCd(hier.getParentHierCd());
        committees.add(committee);
    }
    return committees;
}
```

Above code is returning like below, it's returning data into only in two level(parent and child), but i need to get data in deep with recursive like I mentioned below.

```
 > TEA 
   > TEA-1
   > TEA-2
   > TEA-3
 > ITC 
   > ITC-1
   > ITC-2
```

Result should be like below

```
 > TEA 
   > TEA-1
     > TEAA-1
       > TEAAA-1
     > TEAA-2
   > TEA-2
   > TEA-3
 > ITC 
   > ITC-1
      > ITCA-1
      > ITCA-2
   > ITC-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive function approach for resolving this. like need to find the sub child is available for the parent or not . based on that call committeeBuilder